# "Add a domain" not visible after sandbox refresh

Tags: certificates, custom-domain, digital-experience

The first picture is of the production -> Setup-> Domains
[image: Production]

The second picture is of the sandbox-> Setup-> Domains. The add domain button disappeared after sandbox refreh
[image: Sandbox After refresh]

Is there anyway i can make the button apprear again for System administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Sandboxes created or refreshed since Spring '21, the domain list is read-only and is kept up-to-date with the list in production. Changes made to the domain list in production are propagated to the sandboxes and 'Add a Domain button will not be available in the sandbox.

If you're trying to set up a custom domain in a sandbox, add it to the production org and choose that sandbox from the Associated Org drop-down field. Be sure to activate
the change to have it take effect.

Check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000358315&type=1) along with [Test Your Custom Domains in a Sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_mgmt_sandbox_custom_domains.htm&type=5).